# How can I spoof source ip address while making a ping request from windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, ip, spoofing

I am using ping command to test my website which is running on a local server at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I spoof source ip address while making a ping request from
>   windows command prompt?

If you just want to change your local network address (e.g., change from 192.168.1.69 to 192.168.1.70) then you can set a different static IP address in the Windows "Network and Sharing Center". The exact steps depend on what version of Windows you are using, but should be available on google.

If you want to spoof your actual Internet IP address you may have to find and proxy server, log into that proxy server, and then ping from that machine.

Comment: Any good articles about the second scenario? I am on W7.

Comment: I want to know how I can route ping traffic through a proxy chain entirely using windows command prompt.

Comment: There are various proxy server lists on the internet. If you telnet to a proxy server and then ping from that server the ping will look like it is coming from the proxy (unless it forwards your IP, which some do, and some don't).

Comment: How can I figure out which proxy forwards ip and which does not?

Comment: Try and see, or use one that's known not to forward. The ones on this list all appear to not forward: http://www.proxylisty.com/ip-proxylist

Comment: You can also purchase proxy services if you want a more reliable connection.

Comment: Is it legal to establish telnet connection to these proxy servers?

Comment: Unauthorized access is typically not legal. On the other hand, if these servers are offering free anonymous access (where your credentials are just username "anonymous") then likely it is legal to use. However, this is dependent on your local laws in your country of origin as well as the country where the server is located... You will have to figure it out for yourself, or ask a local lawyer.

Comment: I should also mention. Even if it is legal to use a proxy server, it might still not be safe to do so. So proceed with caution.

Comment: neither of those are actually "spoofing". Spoofing means to change the actual packets to pretend they are coming from somewhere else, and, afaik this cannot be done on windows as they do not allow you to modify raw packets.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean spoof and what you mean IP.

If you want to be a specific IP4 or IP6 it may not be possible. Such as you pretending to come from Google's IP. But if you just want to test various IPs against a security firewall that's different.

You can generally find VPN like hidemyass.com to use their IP. Some are anonymous, others not so much. Some offer services like different countries or cities, some are pay some are not. Some record activity some not.

If you want to spoof an IP on an intranet then it is just a matter of changing the ip within the modem adapter.

BPID Security

Answer (score 1):

If by spoofing your address you mean "I have address `A` and want to pretend that my request comes from address `B`" then you must be aware that the reply from the system will go to address `B` (and be discarded).

In other words, while there are some possibilities to spoof an address, this is always a one-way trip: you will not get an answer to your request.